# Making a graphics card using transistors

Tags: transistors, vga, graphics

Is it possible to make a graphics card using no ICs that uses a VGA cable and outputs, say, 16px by 16px? Or are too many transistors required for it to be realistic? (Too many meaning more than 500.)

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it may not be realistic. You should define the bit depth (how many colors) and the resolution (such as 640x480@60Hz) where the 16 by 16 pixels are shown.

Comment: If your talking about a 'graphics card' rather than some sort of entire system, the other problem is where is the video going to come from. Using direct mapped IO on the main system bus of a 1MHz 8 bit processor might be doable with only transistors. Handling the state machine for 100MHz PCIe is a very different matter, and pretty much impossible.

Comment: We didn't have commercial graphics terminals until the early 1970's (I can't speak to military.) And even then, they were very expensive. I saw one demonstrated at PSU in 1973. It was, at the time, about US$30k and it didn't do that much, anyway. Many projects used TVs as displays (TV Typewriter, for example.) But even then not really as programmable graphics (as that required a LOT of RAM which cost a LOT of money.) It wasn't until Intel was finally pushing out DRAM in bulk (mid-to-late 1970's) that there was much chance. The memory will kill you, here, even if you can do the rest.

Comment: Can you do it without transistors, really? I believe you mean discrete transistors OP. In the end, an IC is nothing more than many transistors...

Comment: Are any other components permitted (diodes, resistors, capacitors etc.)? What would you use it for?

Comment: Ben Eater has a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7rce6IQDWs) where he made a VGA video card from logic ICs on a breadboard. Not quite transistors, but it gives an idea of the level of effort involved and what kind of result you can expect. Also has a lot of useful information about how VGA works.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not realistic to make a graphics card without ICs.

You describe VGA so I'll consider a graphics card to be a VGA display-only adaptor, supporting a 16 x 16 image with VGA timing at 25 MHz, the lowest frequency recognisably for VGA.

It would have to use transistors (FETs) for everything. For example, four FETs would be needed for every 2-input logic gate. You'd need over a hundred logic gates and flip-flops for the control circuitry. Just an address counter with limits checking and reload uses quite a lot of gates.

Then 256 bits of memory, which would need six FETs per bit for static memory, two FETs and a capacitor for dynamic.

The resultant large physical size would make it unrealistic, or just plain 'very difficult', to get the circuit to work reliably in producing a good quality display at 25 MHz. You'd run into a lot of line propagation delay problems.

As a minimum, one would probably opt for a cheap CPLD or FPGA to achieve 16x16 on VGA instead. So that's what your non-IC circuit is competing with when you're appraising what's realistic.

Comment: It might be feasible to make one output a fixed grey level. I'm sure I've seen video of someone playing around with generating composite video using a couple of 555 timers, showing what happened when he played around with the amplitudes and frequencies, and getting a couple of greyscale bars on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what you consider a "graphics card".

Magnavox had a video game called the Odyssey that would display Pong like games on a television set using only transistors and diodes.
VGA can be done using a handful of logic ICs (https://nerdhut.de/2018/08/08/vga-signal-generation/), so it might be possible to do something at a lower resolution using discrete transistors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a scan-type system can be made to use few transistors
and drive a display.   What you cannot do with under 500
transistors, is STORE a frame to be displayed, in RAM.
An alternate storage scheme might be acoustic delay lines,
with an amplify-refresh during each cycle.

This is because a 16 x 16 display digital storage requirement is
256 bits for each of three colors... and it takes
two transistors to make a simple memory (latch).
Something to accept input and drive RGB display would need a few
extra transistors, but the latches alone would
amount to 1536 devices (and show only 7 colors).

Intel historically started with a RAM chip as its first
product; it was a 64-bit memory, the 3101.   When you can
print transistors by the hundreds, memory was the showpiece
in effective competition against discrete transistor designs.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can.

Before doing that, you should have adequate courage and ability, a little talent.

It will be an enormous project, take a long time.

Aren’t you see any amazing projects done by electricians only involves transistors?

That’s really amazing for non professional guys.

I don’t recommend you to do that, DIY a graphical card only with transistors even as if you think you’ve brilliant enough.

There’re some software platform supporting circuit simulation.

Like Cadence Pspice, ElectronicWorkbench, etc. More powerful simulate design suite available.

Proteus is much friendly to newbies and it supports common use basic components on market.

So it’s really a good suggestion for you to build a graphical card you thought.

If you can build it in the virtual environment, then it’s only a time problem to come true.